# Print automático após HTML estar carregado com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Ao clicar em um botão para a impressão de um relatório, este deverá consultar com o AngularJS algumas informações na base de dados e logo executar o comando para a impressão (`$window.print()`) depois que a página já estiver carregada com as devidas informações.

Quando tento fazer isto, ele vai para a visualização de impressão antes da página esteja carregada por completo. É certo que simplesmente o usuário esperar a mesma carregar e clicar em imprimir poderia resolver mas, no meu caso, a impressão automática ficaria bem mais interessante.

Necessito que o comando `$window.print()` seja executado somente depois que as devidas informações já estiverem na página.

Como faço esta verificação?

---- Editado:

Existe um service específico onde faz a consulta dos dados de um determinado funcionário e uma verificação referente (`r.sucesso`) sobre a consulta. Este código encontra-se dentro do controlador correspondente da tela em específico.

```
funcionarioService.getListagem(self.funcionarioId, function (r) { 
        if (r.sucesso) { 
            self.funcionario = r.conteudo;

            // Estranhamente desta forma soluciona meu problema
            // Acredito que este é executado após o carregamento total da página, 
            // mas não encontrei nenhuma confirmação a respeito.
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                window.print()
            }, 1); 
        }           
    });
```

---- Editado[2]:

Este [link](http://viniciuswebdev.com/javascript-settimeout-assincrono-concorrente/) fala a respeito do motivo desta solução proposta funcionar mas não ficou muito claro a explicação.

Comment: Quais são as informações que faltam? é um pedido ajax que decorre ou chega com `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Já fiz tentativa utilizando este comando, mas não deu certo, pois o mesmo é executado depois que os scripts são carregados mas antes que o Angular coloque as informação de sua chamada ajax na página.

Comment: Então podes colocar o `window.print()` dentro do `success(function(data, status, headers, config) {` do Angular.

Comment: Para esta tentativa os campos referentes ficam vazios e depois que cancelo a impressão, os dados aparecem.

Comment: Você pode dar um `timeout` na sua impressão, apesar de que isso não garante que a página estará 100% completa em todas as vezes

Comment: Ok, está na hora de colocares o código que tens e se possivel um exemplo do problema a funcionar num site ou jsFiddle. Senão vamos estar a adivinhar o que pode ser :)

Comment: Verificando no navegador a página leva em torno de 1.79s (valor de acordo o navegador) para carregar, porém utilizando window.setTimeout(function() { window.print()}, 1); o meu problema é solucionado. Achei muito estranho o fato de colocar apenas 1ms de tempo o problema ser solucionado. Acredito que este é executado após o carregamento total da página.

Comment: Onde estás a usar `funcionarioService.getListagem`?

Comment: No SO gringo tem uma boa discussão sobre isso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715256/angularjs-event-to-call-after-content-is-loaded

Comment: Eu uso essa diretiva **ng-cloak** no body ela faz com que o angular aguarde o carregamento da página. Faz o teste talvez não precise do timeout. [ng-cloak documentação oficial](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Comment: @Sergio: Dentro do controlador da página

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta encontrada

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.print()
}, 0);
```

é válida, pois não apenas de acordo com este [link](http://viniciuswebdev.com/javascript-settimeout-assincrono-concorrente/) que eu tinha colocado, mas nesta [outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058612/does-calling-settimeout-clear-the-callstack) é colocado:

> Async invocations, such as those from setTimeout, do indeed generate a new callstack.

onde traduzido seria algo do tipo que `setTimeout` gera uma nova pilha para invocações assíncronas, sendo executada após a até então a última pilha.